# xml.Unmarshal error: "expected element type <Item> but have <Items>"

Tags: go

I'm trying to unmarshal the following XML, but am receiving an error.

```
<ItemSearchResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01">
<Items>
<Item>
<ASIN>B005XSS8VC</ASIN>
</Item>
</Items>
```

Here are my structs:

```
type Product struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"Item"`
    ASIN    string
}

type Result struct {
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"ItemSearchResponse"`
    Products []Product `xml:"Items"`
}
```

The text of the error is "expected element type `<Item>` but have `<Items>`," but I can't see where I'm going wrong. Any help is appreciated.

```
v := &Result{Products: nil}
err = xml.Unmarshal(xmlBody, v)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for me (note the `Items>Item`):

```
type Result struct {
XMLName       xml.Name `xml:"ItemSearchResponse"`
Products      []Product `xml:"Items>Item"`
}

type Product struct {
    ASIN   string `xml:"ASIN"`
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The structure of the struct doesn't match with the xml structure, here is a working code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "log"
)

type Product struct {
    ASIN    string   `xml:"ASIN"`
}
type Items struct {
    Products    []Product `xml:"Item"`
}

type Result struct {
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"ItemSearchResponse"`
    Items    Items `xml:"Items"`
}

func main() {
    xmlBody := `<ItemSearchResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01">
<Items>
<Item>
<ASIN>B005XSS8VC</ASIN>
</Item>
<Item>
<ASIN>C005XSS8VC</ASIN>
</Item>
</Items>`
    v := &Result{}
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(xmlBody), v)
    log.Println(err)
    log.Printf("%+v", v)

}
```

it will output:

```
&{XMLName:{Space:http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01 Local:ItemSearchResponse} Products:{Products:[{ASIN:B005XSS8VC} {ASIN:C005XSS8VC}]}}
```

Comment: I thought the whole point of the `xml:…` tags was that the structure of the struct didn't need to match that of the XML. This makes sense though, and explains why my solution below works (because using Items>Item "skips" the Items struct).